# How to use months_between function in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `EMP`, I need the months difference between their `HIREDATE` to present date.

I used `MONTHS_BETWEEN` function and I wrote this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    HIREDATE, SYSDATE, MONTHS_BETWEEN (SYSDATE, HIREDATE) AS DIFF 
FROM 
    EMP
```

Output

```
  HIREDATE     SYSDATE     DIFF
  ---------   --------- ----------
    17-DEC-80 31-JAN-14 397.452866
    20-FEB-81 31-JAN-14 395.356092
    22-FEB-81 31-JAN-14 395.291576
    02-APR-81 31-JAN-14 393.936737
```

But I need the same output in SQL Server 2008, I tried using `DATEDIFF` function like this:

```
  Declare @Date1 datetime 
  Declare @Date2 datetime 
  set @Date1 = (SELECT GETDATE());
  set @Date2 = (SELECT HIREDATE FROM SCOTT.EMP )

  SELECT 
      DATEDIFF(MONTH, @Date1, @Date2) AS DifferenceOfDay
```

But I got error message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Please help me writing a query in SQL Server 2008 as to get same output...

Comment: set @Date2 = (SELECT HIREDATE FROM SCOTT.EMP )
 is going to return multiple rows. This will fail.

Comment: You can get the day difference and convert it to month.

Answer (score 0):

To Fix your original query, try the following.

```
SELECT HIREDATE
  , SYSDATE
  , DATEDIFF(MONTH, [HIREDATE], GETDATE()) AS DifferenceOfDay 
FROM SCOTT.EMP
```

Your original error is because the following variable assignment is going to return more than 1 value.

```
set @Date2 = (SELECT HIREDATE FROM SCOTT.EMP )
```

Comment: set @Date2 = (SELECT HIREDATE FROM SCOTT.EMP where ename='smith')      if i write like this i can have the output, but i need for all employees

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a similar query, please use this.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(M, HIREDATE, GETDATE()) FROM SCOTT.EMP
```

Here's a link to the [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) documentation.